# How can one prevent the ability to click and drag the viewport for safari on iPad or iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

I have a larger problem with swipes not being registered. And I believe its because the SDK's assume you would want to click an drag the entire viewport of Safari instead of any of the divs that could be in it.

How can I prevent this default?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to listen for the [`touchmove`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) event and call `event.preventDefault()` therein on any elements you don't want to contribute to viewport movement.

jquery example:

```
$('.interestingElements').on('touchmove', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

In mobile safari, the default behavior for a `touchmove` involving a single touch is to slide the viewport around.

If two touches are involved, the default behavior is to trigger a `gesture` event.  Preventing default on touchmove prevents the gesture event from ever firing.  You can use the `changedTouches` array to find out how many touches are involved in this touchmove event.  Good luck!